# How to write some texts in this picture?

Tags: graphics, pstricks

I have a file

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{esvect}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(10,4)
\psline{->}(1,1)(0,0)
\psline{->}(1,1)(3,1)
\psline{->}(1,1)(0,3)
\psline{->}(7,1)(5,0)
\psline{->}(7,1)(9,0)
\psline{->}(7,1)(7,3)
\rput[tl](0.61,0.59){$\vv{a}$}
\rput[tl](1.72,1.5){$\vv{b}$}
\rput[tl](0.68,2.38){$\vv{c}$}
\rput[tl](8.14,0.78){$\vv{a}$}
\rput[tl](5.47,0.82){$\vv{b}$}
\rput[tl](6.4,1.97){$\vv{c}$}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

I want to write some texts like the picture. How to get them? 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you would place it the same way that you placed the labels, just need to choose where it is to go. I used:

```
\rput[tl](0.0,-1.0){Some Text}
\rput[tl](6.0,-1.0){Some More Text}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{esvect}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-1,-2)(10,4)
\psline{->}(1,1)(0,0)
\psline{->}(1,1)(3,1)
\psline{->}(1,1)(0,3)
\psline{->}(7,1)(5,0)
\psline{->}(7,1)(9,0)
\psline{->}(7,1)(7,3)
\rput[tl](0.0,-1.0){Some Text}
\rput[tl](6.0,-1.0){Some More Text}
\rput[tl](0.61,0.59){$\vv{a}$}
\rput[tl](1.72,1.5){$\vv{b}$}
\rput[tl](0.68,2.38){$\vv{c}$}
\rput[tl](8.14,0.78){$\vv{a}$}
\rput[tl](5.47,0.82){$\vv{b}$}
\rput[tl](6.4,1.97){$\vv{c}$}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{esvect}
\psset
{
    arrowsize=3pt 2,
    arrowinset=0.25,
    arrows=->,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(10,4)
\psline(1,1)(0,0)
\psline(1,1)(3,1)
\psline(1,1)(0,3)
\psline(7,1)(5,0)
\psline(7,1)(9,0)
\psline(7,1)(7,3)
\rput[tl](0.61,0.59){$\vv{a}$}
\rput[tl](1.72,1.5){$\vv{b}$}
\rput[tl](0.68,2.38){$\vv{c}$}
\rput[tl](8.14,0.78){$\vv{a}$}
\rput[tl](5.47,0.82){$\vv{b}$}
\rput[tl](6.4,1.97){$\vv{c}$}
\uput[-90](1,-0.25){Some Text}
\uput[-90](7,-0.25){Some More Text}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Explanations:

- Use `standalone` document class to get a tight PDF output.
- Remove unnecessary packages.
- Remove unnecessary settings.
- Don't use starred `pspicture` if you have no objects beyond the specified canvas region.
- Repetitive `{->}` for multiple consecutive `\psline` can be removed and defined as a common settings before `\psline`.
- Use either `\rput` or `\uput` to put a label.

### Edit:

It will be more convenient if you use `\pcline` followed by `\n*put` as follows,

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{esvect}
\psset
{
    arrowsize=3pt 2,
    arrowinset=0.25,
    arrows=->,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(10,4)
\pcline(1,1)(0,0)\naput{$\vv{a}$}
\pcline(1,1)(3,1)\naput{$\vv{b}$}
\pcline(1,1)(0,3)\nbput{$\vv{c}$}
\pcline(7,1)(9,0)\naput{$\vv{a}$}
\pcline(7,1)(5,0)\nbput{$\vv{b}$}
\pcline(7,1)(7,3)\naput{$\vv{c}$}
\uput[-90](1,-0.25){Some Text}
\uput[-90](7,-0.25){Some More Text}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I get the file 'standalone.sty'? I have standalone.dtx.

Comment: @minthao_2011: Why do you need `standalone.sty`? My code above used `standalone.cls` that should be installed when you install TeX Live or MikTeX.

Comment: My computer can not run your code. I do not understand why. This is the *.log fiel, I uploaded here http://www.mediafire.com/?gqluwrr7ce0ad4p Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @minthao_2011: Please install the latest MikTeX. Your current PSTricks package did not recognize `arrowsize` option, you can try to remove the `arrowsize`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wil install the latest MikTeX.